# my global can't change in the def of a class

Tags: python

I define a varible, name 'Decisoin_name' and set -1 at first

and I try to change it in a def of a class

because I’d like  to add 1 everytime when I call the def

but the system send me a message

> "local variable 'Decision_name' referenced before assignment"

what can I do?

Would you give me a solution to fix it ? thank you

The following is my code

```
Decision_name = -1

class Decision_Dialog(QDialog):

    def sendback(self):

        Decision_name+=1

        print(Decision_name)

        self.close()
```

Comment: Put `global Decision_name` inside the `def`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change a global name from a class method directly, you need to declare it as a *global* variable beforehand:

```
class Decision_Dialog(QDialog):
    def sendback(self):
        global Decision_name
        Decision_name += 1
```

---

Although if it does not need to be a global variable, you can take different routes e.g. make it a class variable and let each instance modify to it's need, or make it a instance variable by defining in `__init__` and make necessary changes afterwards.

Also, you should be using *snake_case* for variable names e.g. `decision_name`.

Comment: but system send me a message:  'Decision_name' is used prior to global declaration

Comment: thank you~~ I fix it .of couse for your help